# Fill one column by excluding specific values in another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For a dataframe `df`, I'm trying to fill column `b` by value `2017-01-01` if the values in column `a` are either empty `NaNs` or `Others`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['Coffee','Muffin','Donut','Others',pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan]})
        a
0  Coffee
1  Muffin
2   Donut
3  Others
4     NaN
5     NaN
```

The expected result is like this:

```
        a           b
0  Coffee  2017-01-01
1  Muffin  2017-01-01
2   Donut  2017-01-01
3  Others         NaN
4     NaN         NaN
5     NaN         NaN
```

What I have tried which didn't exclude `NaNs`:

```
df.loc[~df['a'].isin(['nan', 'Others']), 'b'] = '2017-01-01'

        a           b
0  Coffee  2017-01-01
1  Muffin  2017-01-01
2   Donut  2017-01-01
3  Others         NaN
4     NaN  2017-01-01
5     NaN  2017-01-01
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code you typed to get that result?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Updated.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to fill in the date string if its NOT 'NaN' or 'others'

Comment: yes, just example data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.nan` instead `nan`:

```
df.loc[~df['a'].isin([np.nan, 'Others']), 'b'] = '2017-01-01'
```

Or before comparing replace missing values by `Others`:

```
df.loc[~df['a'].fillna('Others').eq('Others'), 'b'] = '2017-01-01'
print (df)
        a           b
0  Coffee  2017-01-01
1  Muffin  2017-01-01
2   Donut  2017-01-01
3  Others         NaN
4     NaN         NaN
5     NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

check this out:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['Coffee', 'Muffin', 'Donut', 'Others', pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan]})
conditions = [
    (df['a'] == 'Others'),
    (df['a'].isnull())
]
choices = [np.nan, np.nan]
df['color'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='2017-01-01')

print(df)
```

Comment: thanks, I have one question, why do you need two dates as `choices`?

Comment: One choice for each condition

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['Coffee','Muffin','Donut','Others',pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan]})


df.loc[df['a'].replace('Others',np.nan).notnull(),'b'] = '2017-01-01'

print(df)
```